# Get an array of data when saving in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I  have a form in reactjs application where I render some radio buttons.

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    car: "BMW",
    colors: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "red"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "blue"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    car: "Audi",
    colors: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "green"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "white"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Success:", values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      {items.map((i) => {
        return (
          <Form.Item
            label={i.car}
            key={i.car}
            name={"carId" + i.id}
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please" }]}
          >
            <Radio.Group>
              {i.colors.map((color) => {
                return (
                  <Radio key={color.text} value={color.text}>
                    {color.text}
                  </Radio>
                );
              })}
            </Radio.Group>
          </Form.Item>
        );
      })}

      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Now when I save data I get:

```
{
carId1: "red",
carId2: "white"
}
```

Issue: I want to get data after saving in this way:

```
[
  {
    carId: 1,
    colors: ["red"]
  },
  {
    carId: 2,
    colors: ["white"]
  }
]
```

Question: How to get the same structure that I described above after saving the form?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4102-forked-o3to7?file=/index.js:320-1730

Comment: You have all the needed data, you can customize the structure as you like, [check here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4102-forked-cn6sc), I did some chanegs in OnFinish

Comment: @Zac, i can't access the link, the editor does not open

Answer (score 0):

I've added a link in comments with a simple data restructure solution, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4102-forked-cn6sc?file=/index.js:686-929)
in case of it's not opening,
I've just updated the onFinish method to be:

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
    const results = [];
    items.forEach((carItem) => {
      results.push({
        carId: carItem.id,
        colors: [values["carId" + carItem.id]]
      });
    });
    console.log("Success:", results);
  };
```

so you have the needed data and can structure it in any shape you want.

Comment: is there a possibility to get the same structure after saving but without doing manipulations with `items` in `onFinish`? EX: save the fom and to get inside `values` from `onFinish` the above structure.